# SwiftUI Textfield with value validation when submitted

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I tried to build a `NumberField` from a `TextField` where the value is validated and pushed along the `Binding` only when the `.onSubmit` modifier is called. The logic seems to work fine but you will see that the `NumberField` is not updated properly when the submitted value is outside the specified range.

Here's my code for the `View`:

```
struct NumberField: View {
    
    init(
        value: Binding<Double>,
        range: ClosedRange<Double>
    ) {
        self._value = value
        self.range = range
        
        self._valueStore = State(initialValue: value.wrappedValue)
    }
    
    @Binding var value: Double
    let range: ClosedRange<Double>
    
    @State private var valueStore: Double
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField(
            "",
            value: .init(
                get: {
                    valueStore
                },
                set: { newValue in
                    valueStore = validate(
                        newValue,
                        range: range
                    )
                }),
            formatter: NumberFormatter()
        )
        .onSubmit {
            value = valueStore
        }
        .onChange(of: value) { newValue in
            guard newValue != valueStore else {
                return
            }
            
            valueStore = newValue
        }
    }
    
    func validate(_ newValue: Double, range: ClosedRange<Double>) -> Double {
        let validatedValue = clamp(newValue, to: range)
        print("validate - newValue: \(newValue) - validated: \(validatedValue)")
        return validatedValue
    }
    
    func clamp(_ value: Double, to range: ClosedRange<Double>) -> Double {
        min(max(range.lowerBound, value), range.upperBound)
    }
}
```

You can use it like so in a playground (or a macOS app):

```
struct MainView: View {
    @State var value = 2.0
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("value: \(value)")
            NumberField(value: $value, range: 2.0 ... 10)
            NumberField(value: $value, range: 2.0 ... 10)
        }
        .frame(width: 200)
        .padding()
    }
    
}
```

Comment: seems to work for me, the `NumberField` is updated properly (i.e. clamped) when the submitted value is outside the specified range. But maybe I don't understand the question well enough.

Comment: In the usage example that I provided, you can see the problem by entering a value outside the range in one of the `NumberField`. When that value is submitted, the other `NumberField` and the `Text` are updated with the clamped value, but the `NumberField` used to submit the value shows the non-validated value.

Comment: Works well for me on macos 13.0 Ventura, using Xcode 14.1-beta3, target macCatalyst and ios-16. Both `NumberField` have the same clamped value.
Tested on real devices, not Previews. It may be different on older systems.